# R - Turning table into dataframe while keeping first column

Tags: r, dataframe

Given original dataframe `df` of form

```
   Date        Cat
   <POSIXct>   <chr>
1  2019-10-3   A
2  2019-10-3   A
3  2019-10-3   B
4  2019-10-4   A
5  2019-10-4   C
6  2019-10-4   C
7  2019-10-4   C
8  2019-10-5   B
9  2019-10-5   C
```

I carry out the operation `df_table <- table(df)` which gives `df_table` of form

```
            Cat
Date        A   B   C
2019-10-3   2   1   0
2019-10-4   1   0   3
2019-10-5   0   1   1
```

because I need the counts of each `Cat` grouped by `Date`.

I need to turn the table into a dataframe and use the values for plotting.
But when trying `as.data.frame.matrix(df_table)`, it gives the output

```
            A      B      C
            <int>  <int>  <int>
2019-10-3   2      1      0
2019-10-4   1      0      3
2019-10-5   0      1      1
```

whereas what I want is

```
Date        A      B      C
<POSIXct>   <int>  <int>  <int>
2019-10-3   2      1      0
2019-10-4   1      0      3
2019-10-5   0      1      1
```

I would want to keep the first column from table as a column in the converted dataframe. Also would want to keep the datatype. It seems the date would become a chr object rather than the original POSIXct object when applying `table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your method, you can further use `tibble::rownames_to_column()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

table(df) %>%
  as.data.frame.matrix() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Date") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date))
```

or in another way use `tidyr::pivot_wider()` with `values_fn = length` for counting:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Cat, 
              values_from = Cat, 
              values_fn = length,
              values_fill = 0)

# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   Date                    A     B     C
#   <dttm>              <int> <int> <int>
# 1 2019-10-03 00:00:00     2     1     0
# 2 2019-10-04 00:00:00     1     0     3
# 3 2019-10-05 00:00:00     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to keep it in a long format if you want to plot.
https://www.statology.org/long-vs-wide-data/

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  count(Date, Cat) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = n, fill = Cat)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge2") + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those Dates in `table()` result are row names, so they don't form a column, though you could `cbind()` that vector to the resulting data.frame and convert it back to `POSIXct` :

```r
df_table <- table(df)
str(df_table)
#>  'table' int [1:3, 1:3] 2 1 0 1 0 1 0 3 1
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ Date: chr [1:3] "2019-10-03" "2019-10-04" "2019-10-05"
#>   ..$ Cat : chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"

df_mt <- cbind(
  dimnames(df_table)[1], 
  as.data.frame.matrix(df_table))

df_mt$Date <- as.POSIXct(df_mt$Date)
df_mt
#>                  Date A B C
#> 2019-10-03 2019-10-03 2 1 0
#> 2019-10-04 2019-10-04 1 0 3
#> 2019-10-05 2019-10-05 0 1 1

str(df_mt)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ Date: POSIXct, format: "2019-10-03" "2019-10-04" ...
#>  $ A   : int  2 1 0
#>  $ B   : int  1 0 1
#>  $ C   : int  0 3 1
```

There's also `as.data.frame.table()`, dates being still strings as they originate from row names :

```r
as.data.frame.table(df_table, stringsAsFactors = F)
#>         Date Cat Freq
#> 1 2019-10-03   A    2
#> 2 2019-10-04   A    1
#> 3 2019-10-05   A    0
#> 4 2019-10-03   B    1
#> 5 2019-10-04   B    0
#> 6 2019-10-05   B    1
#> 7 2019-10-03   C    0
#> 8 2019-10-04   C    3
#> 9 2019-10-05   C    1
```

But you might find it easier to just count & pivot yourself:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  count(Date, Cat) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Cat, 
              values_from = n, 
              values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Date                    A     B     C
#>   <dttm>              <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 2019-10-03 00:00:00     2     1     0
#> 2 2019-10-04 00:00:00     1     0     3
#> 3 2019-10-05 00:00:00     0     1     1
```

Example data:

```r
df_str <- "Date        Cat
1  2019-10-3   A
2  2019-10-3   A
3  2019-10-3   B
4  2019-10-4   A
5  2019-10-4   C
6  2019-10-4   C
7  2019-10-4   C
8  2019-10-5   B
9  2019-10-5   C"

df <- read.table(text = df_str, header = T)
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>